# Relational algebra: Difference between dates

Tags: relational-algebra

Which function should I use to express the difference of dates. End and Start date differences must be more than 3 days.

```
σ EndDate - StartDate > 3 (Residence)
```

> Error at line 1: function "sub" expects arguments of type "number,number" but "date,date" given

**Schema**

```
Residence= {
UID:number, HID:number, StartDate:date, EndDate:date

1, 1, 2022-03-03, 2022-03-06
2, 1, 2022-03-03, 2022-03-07
3, 1, 2022-03-03, 2022-04-08
1, 2, 2022-03-03, 2022-03-06
2, 2, 2022-03-03, 2022-03-07
3, 2, 2022-03-03, 2022-04-04
1, 3, 2022-03-03, 2022-03-06
2, 3, 2022-03-03, 2022-03-07
3, 3, 2022-03-03, 2022-04-10
}
```

[Online editor](https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc/local/uibk/local/0)

Comment: This is not clear. What are you trying to do? What language? What system are you running it on? And what does the documentation say about σ & sub & that error & date operators & getting numbers from differences in dates or from dates? PS There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please put what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Paraphrase or quote with credit from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. If you augment with a link, say what it is doing there via text in your post. (Posts should be self-contained & links die.) PS Please give minimal representative example data. (Not something you happen to be given or using.) PS Please act on everything in my comments.

Comment: The message is telling you that you can't subtract dates. sub/- only takes 2 numbers. Again: What does the documentation/manual/help say about operators on dates? Like you would find if you search for & read every occurrence of "date" & of "subtract" in it. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)